# How to update standard opportunity field in lead conversion through Flow

Tags: apex, soql, community, process-builder, flow

I got a new requirement like whenever any lead is converted. I have to update specific standard field in opportunity.

The requirement is if user assigns the new opportunity to existing account so I have update picklist value existing. If he created new account I have to update new.

So,I created a process in process builder but it works only if user is creating an account.

So,I tried to create flow with process builder. Like if lead isconverted =true. then flow will work. But how to create a flow like if-else condition? If user selects update this, otherwise update something else.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Larson can you look on to this

Comment: At first you can get the account ID which user is mentioning, then compare that variable to check if value of that variable is Null or not based on that you can perform action. You can perform that using DECISION element in visualflow.

Comment: But think once.when user clicks convert button in sfdc it redirects to some standard page doesn't have layout and object.It unable to capture field there. please look on that and try to gave me solution thanks @sfdc rowdy

Comment: Here in your case the new Opp has not been created or committed into the database, but while committing you want to check the condition, hence in that scenario you can start with process builder on Object Opportunity creation with no criteria and call the flow where you pass accountID and check if it existing or the new creation.

Comment: Hey did you understand the requirement.There is no field available in account Id like when we try to do it in process builder or flow.Please don't say with out prior knowledge.If i miss anything please provide any solution like sharing your criteria to solve issue @sfdc rowdy